# JavaToWS Error while generating web service with CXF

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I get the error when generating web service. I have a simple class that i want to create web service.
I am using CXF 2.7 and Tomcat 7 version.

```
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Fail to load class :RequestLimit
at org.apache.cxf.tools.util.AnnotationUtil.loadClass(AnnotationUtil.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.getServiceClass(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:284)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.getServiceBuilder(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:181)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2wsdl.processor.JavaToWSDLProcessor.process(JavaToWSDLProcessor.java:100)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.processWSDL(JavaToWSContainer.java:110)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWSContainer.execute(JavaToWSContainer.java:75)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:103)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:58)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.toolspec.ToolRunner.runTool(ToolRunner.java:40)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.run(JavaToWS.java:77)
at org.apache.cxf.tools.java2ws.JavaToWS.main(JavaToWS.java:45)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about project hasnt been built. I selected Project->Build Automatically in Eclipse.
More information. [Solution here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/441271/)